# How can we figure out why certain uuencoded files are not decoding properly using Python?

Tags: python, uuencode

We are trying to decode some uuencoded PDF files that are embedded in a txt file.

The problem we have is that most of the PDF files decoded just fine using Python's uuencode library. Here is the code:

```
try:
    decoded_file,m=uudecode(fileString)
except:
    decoded_file=''
```

However, some of the files cannot be opened after they are decoded. We receive the message "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

The only thing we could find on Google is that our files could've been encoded using base64 and the Python uuencoding module only supports base32. Is there a way that we could tell whether it was uuencoded using base64 or base32?

Here is an example of a txt file that had an embedded uuencoded pdf that we successfully decoded:
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1108046/000000000011020832/0000000000-11-020832.txt

And here is an example of one that failed:
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/914257/000000000011005978/0000000000-11-005978.txt

While we are decoding these in Python no errors pop up of any kind and everything seems to be working as it should. What could be causing them to not decode properly? Is there a way we could flag this while we are processing them?

Comment: `except:` is *bad*, and you're making yourself effectively blind to any diagnostics Python generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> uu.decode(open('0000000000-11-005978.txt'))
Warning: Trailing garbage
```

The source data itself is damaged. This is further evidenced by the `..` at the beginning of a line near the end.

Comment: Thanks! This turned out to be the issue.

Comment: I just wanna add that even with the Warning, the output PDF can be opened properly. (I extracted the uuencoded part out of the .txt file first) Further, if you replace `..` with `M`, the warning goes away.

Comment: @Ignacio How can you tell from the `..` that it's corrupt? From the [UUEncoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) wikipedia article it seems that `.` is a valid start to the line and `.` is valid within the line.

Comment: I am having same issue, replacing it with M does the job. Is it fine to do? and I have "- " also in some files. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but I've discovered at least one source of bugs encountered when parsing the UUEncoded text in these filings.

I wrote a [github issue describing the problem and provided a reasonable workaround](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100308). It seems to be the python implementation wrongly assumes padding characters are always whitespace.

Here's the workaround:

```py
import binascii
from binascii import a2b_uu
from io import BytesIO

my_bytes = BytesIO()
line_bytes = b'..#0HQ,38-"B4E14]&#0H_'
line = line_bytes.decode(encoding='ascii')
try:
    my_bytes.write(a2b_uu(line))
except binascii.Error as err:
    if 'trailing garbage' in str(err).lower():
        n_bytes = line_bytes[0] - 32
        assert n_bytes <= 45 and n_bytes <= len(line[1:])
        workaround_line = f'M{line[1:]}'  # replace first byte of UUEncoded line with max length specifier (M)
        data = a2b_uu(workaround_line)[:n_bytes]
        print('', workaround_line, data)
        my_bytes.write(data)
    else:
        raise err
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ python -c "import urllib2; print len(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/914257/000000000011005978/0000000000-11-005978.txt').read().decode('uu'))"
43124
```

works just fine.

Comment: That is interesting but I am pretty new to Python so I am not sure how to translate your approach. I tried this and I get the same length as you but when I try to write out the file I get the same error as I got before. The PDF still fails upon being opened in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Ah, I didn't check the resulting PDF for validity, since no exception was thrown during the decode. I can only assume the original is broken.